# Docker 1.9.0 "bridge" versus a custom bridge network results in difference in hosts file and SSH_CLIENT env variable

Tags: docker

Let me first explain what I'm trying to do, as there may be multiple ways to solve this. I have two containers in docker 1.9.0:

- node001 (172.17.0.2) (`sudo docker run --net=<<bridge or test>> --name=node001 -h node001 --privileged -t -i -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup <<image>>`)
- node002 (172.17.0.3) (`,,`)

#### When I launch them with `--net=bridge` I get the correct value for `SSH_CLIENT` when I ssh from one to the other:

`[root@node001 ~]# ssh root@172.17.0.3
root@172.17.0.3's password: 
[root@node002 ~]# env | grep SSH_CLIENT
SSH_CLIENT=172.17.0.3 56194 22
[root@node001 ~]# ping -c 1 node002
ping: unknown host node002`

In docker 1.8.3 I could also use the hostnames I supply when I start them, in 1.8.3 that last ping statement works!

In docker 1.9.0 I don't see anything being added in `/etc/hosts`, and the ping statement fails. This is a problem for me. So I tried creating a custom network...

`docker network create --driver bridge test`

#### When I launch the two containers with `--net=test` I get a *different value* for `SSH_CLIENT`:

`[root@node001 ~]# ssh root@172.18.0.3
root@172.18.0.3's password: 
[root@node002 ~]# env | grep SSH_CLIENT
SSH_CLIENT=172.18.0.1 57388 22
[root@node001 ~]# ping -c 1 node002
PING node002 (172.18.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from node002 (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms`

Note that the ip address is not node001's, it seems to represent the docker host itself. The hosts file is correct though, containing:

`172.18.0.2      node001
172.18.0.2      node001.test
172.18.0.3      node002
172.18.0.3      node002.test`

My current workaround is using docker 1.8.3 with the default `bridge` network, but I want this to work with future docker versions.

- Is there any way I can customize the `test` network to make it behave similarly to the default `bridge` network?

Alternatively:

- Maybe make the default `bridge` network write out the `/etc/hosts` file in docker 1.9.0?

Any help or pointers towards different solutions will be greatly appreciated..

#### Edit: 21-01-2016

Apparently the problem is fixed in 1.9.1, with *bridge* in docker 1.8 and with a *custom* (--net=test) in 1.9.1, now the behaviour is correct:

`[root@node001 tmp]# ip route
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.5`

`[root@node002 ~]# env | grep SSH_CLIENT
SSH_CLIENT=172.18.0.3 52162 22`

Retried in 1.9.0 to see if I wasn't crazy, and yeah there the problem occurs:

`[root@node001 tmp]# ip route
default via 172.18.0.1 dev eth0 
172.18.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.18.0.3`

`[root@node002 ~]# env|grep SSH_CLI
SSH_CLIENT=172.18.0.1 53734 22`

So after remove/stop/start-ing the instances the IP-addresses were not exactly the same, but it can be easily seen that the ssh_client source ip is not correct in the last code block. Thanks @sourcejedi for making me re-check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think it's possible to change any settings on the default network, i.e. to write `/etc/hosts`.  You apparently can't delete the default networks, so you can't recreate them with different options.

Secondly

> Docker is careful that its host-wide iptables rules fully expose containers to each other’s raw IP addresses, so connections from one container to another should always appear to be originating from the first container’s own IP address. [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/)

I tried reproducing your issue with the random containers I've been playing with.  Running wireshark on the bridge interface for the network, I didn't see my ping packets.  From this I conclude my containers are indeed talking directly to each other; the host was not doing routing and NAT.

You need to check the routes on your client container `ip route`.  Do you have a route for `172.18.0.2/16`?  If you only have a default route, it could try to send everything through the docker host.  And it might get confused and do masquerading as if it was talking with the outside world.

This might happen if you're running some network configuration in your privileged container.  I don't know what's happening if you're just booting it with `bash` though.

Comment: Your answer made me re-check and I found out that it was a problem with 1.9.0, I edited my answer for people experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Wow.  You're right, I have docker 1.9.1 on my system so that's what I must have been testing.